# Otto Event Bus obsolete event detection

Tags: android, otto

Let's say the following sequence of operation happens.

1. Activity A starts
2. Long delay network call ReqA made
3. Before ReqA completes switch to Activity B
4. Quickly switch back to Activity A
5. Same call ReqB is made (ReqA not complete yet)
6. Somehow ReqB completes first and list is populated from response data
7. Now ReqA completes and list is populated again.

But I dont want to show data from ReqA now. What is the best practice in these situations ?
for example I could decide based on request timestamp or on each registration I could increment activity id so that the old events id doesnt match with the new one etc etc.

Comment: Depends on what you are using for making network requests but you can cancel pending network requests before making ReqB.

Comment: OkHttp async request

Comment: It does have `call.cancel();` function to cancel a call. Use it appropriately according to your need before calling a request 2nd time.

Comment: Still the request could be complete before cancel succeeds.

Comment: If ReqB isn't made yet then what's the problem with completing the ReqA? If you want to cancel it before going to ActivityB then call cancel function there.

Comment: Well I will have arbitrary number of request beside request A. So I would have to keep track of all of them if I want to cancel the call before going to second activity. Secondly if  request A completes before request B then I will be setting data twice. Will be a ui glitch.